Blazor: Feature 'Razor TagHelperProvider Feature' is currently unavailable due to an internal error
I got this error in VS 2022 (latest 17.12 Preview 2.1).

Blazor: Feature 'Razor TagHelperProvider Feature' is currently unavailable due to an internal error

If you watch the stack trace it says
StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__155`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceConnection`1.<TryInvokeAsync>d__18`1.MoveNext()
RPC server exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements...

The error occurs also in elder versions of VS. It came somehow out of a sudden, but in the cycle of updates, pulling code from others and own work it was hard to tell when exactly.

I had several (blazor) components in a library project. These are purely code components, C# classes that inherit Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputBase, as an example.
The error occurred because in one of my files I missed the namespace keyword. The error comes immediately if one removes namespace and disappears after adding again.
Usually this doesn't happen, but I have copied and pasted a class file and this operation - in the root of the project - removed the namespace (I'd call it a UI glitch in VS 2022). After adding and reworking the file the interesting point is, that the project (and this particular component) works as expected. Hence, I never thought that this is the culprit.
After lot of debugging I found the missing namespace element and after adding it the Razor TagHelperProvider error immediately disappeared. Seems that the provider service tries to pull the namespace and expects one (hence, Single) and found none.
